# How to call PowerShell script from WSL?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my Windows directory

```
C:\Users\jholmes\pichak\analytics
```

I have run1.ps1 code.
I run wsl.exe, now my pwd is

```
   /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32
```

How to point to the first path and execute the script?

Comment: Hey did you try traversing back? cd .. from your PWD and traverse to \Users\jholmes\pichak\analytics ? Also how do you want to execure .ps1 scripts in linux?

Comment: @AvidJoe Impossible,I am still in Linux after cd ..

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. If you are already inside Ubuntu or any subsystem, the mount point for accessing windows directories is mnt/ you can traverse to any windows volume from the mnt/ for example. /mnt/c/Users/jholmes/pichak/analytics would be accessible from your linux subsystem.  Im not sure what you mena when you say i run wsl.exe. If this isnt the case I might be completely wasting your time as well. lol.. sorry

Comment: If you wish to run windows tools (like powershell) from Linux please see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-windows-tools-from-linux , if you wish to do it vice versa please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-linux-tools-from-a-windows-command-line . in your case going back with cd and running with powershell <path>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. You can change your working directory to that of your shell script and execute it normally. To do so, follow these steps:

- Mount the relevant drive `cd /mnt/c/`.
- Change directories according to the path of the script.

2. This approach is more of a hack that I use for the sake of convenience. I have created a folder in my Windows storage wherein I store all Ubuntu WSL related files. Say, `D:\Ubuntu`. To avoid changing the working directory every time you open WSL, you can modify the shell profile file (bashrc, zshrc etc.) to load the relevant directory at the end.

- i.e., Add `cd /mnt/d/Ubuntu/` at the end of your `~/.zshrc` file if you use zsh or the relevant profile file otherwise.

Comment: I *really* recommend that new users (at least) stay away from the "adding a `cd` in the startup config` hack.  I see too many questions from folks who have done this and it messes with them later.

Answer (score 13):

In WSL2, using the `-File` option worked for me:

```
powershell.exe -File path/to/script.ps1
```

Comment: `powershell.exe -F ~/win/common/utils/fix_wsl.ps1` gives me an **Error** saying `The argument '/home/user/win/common/utils/fix_wsl.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.`

Comment: Cd to the dir and executing PowerShell with file in current dir works though.

Answer (score 2):

For me [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69493187/11159476) was almost the good one but when running for instance:

```
powershell.exe -File /mnt/c/path/to/script/script.ps1
```

I got following error:

```
The argument '/mnt/c/path/to/script/script.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
```

I then have to:

```
cd /mnt/c/path/to/script
powershell.exe -File script.ps1
```

Comment: I get this, also.  Is there any way to use a full absolute path like this?  I don't like having to cd to the directory.

Comment: I did not find any way to call with full absolute path, and I don't like to have to `cd` too... Moreover when we want to stay in same folder, we have to `cd -` (or `cd - > /dev/null` if we don't want to have new path echoed).

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers are correct. `powershell.exe` is a Windows program so expects a Windows path as an argument.

```
powershell.exe -File C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Scripts\\Write-EventLog-1777.ps1
```

As the backslash character is used for escaping in Linux, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

Comment: Only this answer worked to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the evidence, that with the WSL2, our software can make the Powershell script encrypted and protected:
[See this picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PClaT.png)

And it can detect and kill the process that uses fanotify because we think it can be used by attackers to hide critical file change (it also can find and kill dtrace/strace/stap/bpftrace/debuggers and process that opens /dev/kmem, /dev/mem, /proc/kcore, and the protected process' /proc/pid/mem etc):
[This picture shows the encrypted PowerShell script now can detect and kill possible attackers' processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjJw5.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).